# Supertrait only when Self : Sized

Tags: rust, traits

Lets suppose I have a trait

```
trait A {
    fn new() -> Self where Self : Sized;
    fn foo(&self) -> i32;
}
struct B {
   data : i32
}
impl A for B {
    fn new() -> Self {
        B {data : 42}
    }
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        self.data
    }
}
```

Now I can use `Box<dyn A>`, I just do not have the new() method available.
And when I have a generic `T : A`, I can do `T::new()`. So I can use A as a trait object (without the functions which would prevent this) and I can use it in a templated code and use all functions on it.

My question is, is it possible to get this behavior when having for example `Clone` as supertrait?
In the `dyn A` case `A` does not implement Clone. In the generic case is does.

Comment: So if I understand correctly. You want to conditionally implement `Clone` based on whether the type implementing the trait `A` is `Sized`?

Comment: @Wazner It sounds like he wants to make `A` a _supertrait_ of `Clone` only when `Self: Sized`.

Comment: @Wazner
I want to make `Clone` supertrait of `A` if and only if `Self :Sized`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that:

```rust
trait A {
    fn new() -> Self where Self : Sized;
    fn foo(&self) -> i32;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct B {
   data : i32
}

impl A for B {
    fn new() -> Self {
        B {data : 42}
    }
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        self.data
    }
}


fn make_clone<T: Clone + A>(toc: &T) -> T {
    dbg!(toc.foo());
    toc.clone()
}

fn main() {
    let b = B{data: 0};
    make_clone(&b);
}
```

so you can access `A` method and the`Clone` supertrait from `make_clone`, you can obviously do the same thing with a supertrait instead of a generic method